# Is it possible to upgrade a Heroku app's buildpack after the app has been created?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an existing node.js app on heroku and I want to upgrade the node.js version by supplying a 0.6.7 buildpack.

Is it possible to update the buildpack a Heroku app is assigned?

If not, what is the suggested path for upgrading the builpack an app uses?

If I have to deploy a new app, how do I made sure the addons don't die?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 27):

This should be possible if you have a public git repo (e.g. a fork of https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs).

To update the buildpack you're using, set the BUILDPACK_URL config using the Heroku CLI:

`heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git`

(Note: replace the git URL with the URL of your buildpack.

Comment: Does this actually work? @MateodelNorte were you able to try this, yet?

Comment: @JesseFulton  Me too. I forgot to report back. Thanks @NaamanNewbold!

Comment: Confirmed by https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack

Answer (score 1):

heroku create myapp --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby

> Previously you could set a config var for BUILDPACK_URL, this value will still be used if set, though a buildpack value set through the CLI will take precedence. BUILDPACK_URL as a config var is now deprecated in favor of the buildpack value on the API and in the future will be migrated.

Source: [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

Comment: According to the documentation this command is only for creating an app. There is a separate commend listed for updating a buildpack (see my answer). Given the age of this answer, instructions may have just changed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Setting a Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application) section of Heroku's buildpack documentation (June 2021)

> **Setting a buildpack on an application**
>
> You can change the buildpack used by an application by setting the buildpack value. When the application is next pushed, the new buildpack will be used.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
Buildpack set. Next release on random-app-1234 will use heroku/php.
Run `git push heroku master` to create a new release using this buildpack.
```

You can also change it to a specific, unofficial one like this:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/some/buildpack.git -a myapp
```

more details available on the linked page, which also includes information on how to set it when creating an app.